# Liferay 6.0: Deploy error

Tags: liferay

I'm in the process of upgrading liferay 5.2 to 6.0.

All went well (not really, I've spent almost 2 months already on this - upgrade ext, db, etc).

Currently I managed to deploy all portlets of mine without any issue except for this one portlet...

After build-service success, then i proceed to do ant deploy and it failed. It return this error:

```
C:\barterfli\liferay\plugins\portlets\MembershipActivation-portlet\docroot\WEB-
INF\src\com\leadingside\portal\membership\service\service\persistence\users_activationPersistenceImpl.java:129: unreported exception 
com.leadingside.portal.membership.service.NoSuchusers_activationException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
return remove(((Long)primaryKey).longValue());
^
C:\barterfli\liferay\plugins\portlets\MembershipActivation-portlet\docroot\WEB-
INF\src\com\leadingside\portal\membership\service\service\persistence\users_activationPersistenceImpl.java:240: unreported exception 
com.leadingside.portal.membership.service.NoSuchusers_activationException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
return findByPrimaryKey(((Long)primaryKey).longValue());
^
```

Can someone help to explain, what's wrong?

I try to manually add the try - catch block inside the PersistenceImpl but the changes will be gone if i build-service (surely thats not the correct way to do it)

Help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have change the compiler of service.
prior to LR6 the compiler was used of older version. So now you have to change the compiler in  one of the build.xml files from plugin SDK.

For further references you can check 
https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/5115695

Comment: I dont hv error regarding running javac.exe.. I can build-service successfully but when i try to deploy, it returns me those error mentioned. And Im not using Eclipse either so I will keep the property "javac.compiler=modern"

Comment: and all my other portlets deployed successfully, except for this one. my build.xml taken from liferay plugins sdk 6.0.6.